# How to allow access for AWS API Gateway to invoke all AWS Lambda functions in any path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm preparing a new AWS API Gateway under few environments - production, staging, testing, development.

Let's say I have two lambda functions connected to the `GET /first` and `GET /second`. Those resources are pointing to the lambda `first:${stageVariables.Qualifier}` (this variable has proper environment value depending on stage).

Now I have to add permissions for API Gateway to invoke both functions. AWS says:

> You defined your Lambda function as a stage variable. Please ensure that you have the appropriate Function Policy on all functions you will use. You can do this by running the below AWS CLI command for each function, replacing the stage variable in the function-name parameter with the necessary function name.

```
aws lambda add-permission
    --function-name arn:aws:lambda:region:000...:function:first:${stageVariables.Qualifier}
    --source-arn arn:aws:execute-api:region:00000:xxxx/*/GET/first
    --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com
    --statement-id 0000-000-0-...
    --action lambda:InvokeFunction
```

So it's clear - I have to invoke this above command 8 times for each configuration:

```
first:development
first:testing
....
second:production
```

Is it possible somehow to add a general permission to allow invocation of any function in any qualifier with any path?

I'm aiming something like that (but it doesn't work):

```
aws lambda add-permission
    --function-name arn:aws:lambda:region:000...:function:*:*
    --source-arn arn:aws:execute-api:region:00000:xxxx/*/*/*
    --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com
    --statement-id 0000-000-0-...
    --action lambda:InvokeFunction
```

Comment: wholesale configuration and management of your cloud deployments is really what tools like CloudFormat, TerraForm et al was born to do.

Comment: @KimBurgaard I think the question was more of -- can I just create a policy in IAM and attach it to all lambdas, instead of executing a command that does essentially that. BTW -- inaccessibly.